# Which email clients are compatible with the calendar of Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: windows, exchange, email-client

I am using Thunderbird at the moment, but the Lighting extension does not work correctly with the calendar of the Exchange Server. I guess this will probably be the same with PostBox and I have heard that Gmail can only do a one-way synchronizations and new events still have to be added directly through OWA.

Any other options (for Windows)?

Comment: Microsoft Outlook!

Comment: You can no longer sync a Calendar with Google Calendar with an Exchange server unless it was setup to be synced before Jan 31 2012.

Answer (score 1):

The followiong clients support Email and calendar:

- Outlook Web App
- Mac Outlook 2011
- Windows Outlook 2010
- Apple Mail 5 (Mac OS X 10.7, Lion)
- Apple Mail 4 and iCal (Mac OS X 10.6, Snow Leopard)
- Astrasync

Take a look at [this article](http://www.crimapp.com/speeches/maacs/page17/page17.html) too.